# chrome.devtools extension panel icon doesn't look right

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

setting a dev tool panel icon in chrome.devtools api from a png renderes offset and moves when I click it. the other stock icons darken when clicked - i assume this is an animation, i'm not sure why or how it's trying to animate my png.

how do i produce an image that will look right as a devtools panel icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect the button image using another DevTools instance (all the images are stored in `chrome-devtools://devtools/Images/toolbarIcons.png`). In `toolbarIcons.png`, the normal and depressed (darkened) image versions are laid out in columns, so you should presumably do the same for your panel icon image.

Comment: thanks! the link helped alot. and is it just me, or did they remove the awesome ability to inspect the inspector in the latest version? i don't see the inspect element option in the right click context menu anymore.

Comment: Just hit `Ctrl-Shift-I` in the inspector when it is undocked - you'll get a new inspector for it.